# After migration to Kubuntu 22.04 desktop and display settings are always lost after (dis)connecting docking station

Tags: kubuntu, multiple-monitors, kde

We are currently migrating our Kubuntu 18.04 clients to 22.04. We do this by installing a custom Kubuntu 22.04 installation and then copying the /home profile.

So far this worked flawlessly on all of our workstations, except for the one single laptop we've upgraded so far.

Whenever the user of this laptop (dis)connects the docking station (tried two already), or restarts Kubuntu, after login, it never restores the desktop icons positions and which external monitor was the primary one. Notes on the desktop are constantly disappearing.

We suspect something of Kubuntu 18.04 keeps interfering with 22.04. I've so far looked in many log files, but could not find anything related.

Any ideas?

We'd like to delete some config files, like

```
.config/KDE
.config/plasma*
.local/share/kscreen
.local/share/sddm
```

Would this a good start?

Unfortunately, my coworker, who setup everything, has left our company, so we are a little bit stranded. (My Kubuntu experience is limited).